# Charging a mobile phone and laptop using wall plug - Series or parallel circuit?

Tags: mains, charging, homework

I'd like to understand if charging multiple devices using the 240 V line's main power plugs forms a series or parallel circuit.

Comment: Consider if it were a series circuit and you unplugged one of the devices - would the other one still work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ALL individual loads from a mains power point are in parallel.
That means that each can be connected or disconnected individually without interrupting energy supply to any others.

Series connected devices will interrupt energy feed as they are added or removed (unless very special and unusual arrangements are made).

There are no examples of series feed for domestic use. Historically there were special case examples of series feed **inside** some equipment. Filaments in valves / tubes in some early radios were in series.

Comment: And the great majority of valve/tube based TVs used series connection for the heaters. Christmas tree lights are invariably series connected.

Comment: Indoor fairy lights were low-voltage bulb in series, but now LEDs are common, they may be wired in parallel

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes - the TV tube filaments and Christmas tree lights (nowadays usually low voltage and not mains directly) are further examples of connection INSIDE an item of equipment. They are interesting but not examples of what the OP asked about. (I am noting this only because, given the level of the question,  the OP may otherwise be confused by such answers).

Answer (score 3):

To add to @russellMcMahon's answer, one major problem with putting loads in series vs. in parallel is that in series, the voltage is split between them, proportionally to their resistance. So if you put a 50 watt incandescent light in series with a 25 watt one (which is twice the resistance), the 50 watt bulb would get 1/3 of the mains voltage (80 volts) and the 25 watt bulb would get 2/3 (160 volts).

Clearly, neither bulb is getting 240 volts and worse, each is getting a different voltage.

Comment: @Frodyne Yes, you are right. I’ll edit it. Thanks